# Detect lazy loading in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5, lazy-loading

I've been tasked with speeding up a giant codebase. One of the things I have noticed is that the team uses lazy loading everywhere. So much so that I think there's a lot to be gained by disabling it. There would be too much of an impact if I disabled it entirely so I'd rather do this in phases.

This got me thinking: is there a way (an event?) to detect when EF is doing something lazily?

In case it matters, we're using EF6, but the context is based on `ObjectContext` instead of `DbContext`.

Due to the mess of the codebase it's not an option to just find references on the navigation properties.

Comment: Something like this might be a start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee835846(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: there's a solution of sorts here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509189/detect-lazy-load-in-entity-framework-core

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/), its a powerful tool for so many things, including EF profiler. You can see how the querys are been translated, and what time each query takes.