# Detect lazy-load in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

Entity Framework Core 3.1.2 - I have enabled `UseLazyLoadingProxies` on my `DbContext` to ensure data integrity, but I want to throw an exception during development if it is used.

How can I execute some code every time EF Core loads a relationship lazily?

Comment: have you tried adding an attribute that tells you if the object is deriving from the "ILazyLoader" interface in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure, if it is then there's a good chance it's loading is deferred, that's all I can think of at the moment anyway, If I get chance I'll have a more in depth look later to day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I know is diagnostic messages. See an example here: https://www.domstamand.com/getting-feedback-from-entityframework-core-through-diagnostics.

The event class you want is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.lazyloadingeventdata.

In the application's DBContext

```
#if DEBUG
    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // In DEBUG mode we throw an InvalidOperationException
        // when the app tries to lazy load data.
        // In production we just let it happen, for data
        // consistency reasons.
        DiagnosticListener.AllListeners.Subscribe(new DbContextDiagnosticObserver());
    }
#endif
```

Then a class to hook into EF notifications

```
internal class DbContextDiagnosticObserver : IObserver<DiagnosticListener>
    {
        private readonly DbContextLazyLoadObserver LazyLoadObserver =
            new DbContextLazyLoadObserver();

        public void OnCompleted() { }

        public void OnError(Exception error) { }

        public void OnNext(DiagnosticListener listener)
        {
            if (listener.Name == DbLoggerCategory.Name)
                listener.Subscribe(LazyLoadObserver);
        }
    }
```

And then finally the class that throws exceptions whenever a lazy load occurrs

```
internal class DbContextLazyLoadObserver : IObserver<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
    {
        public void OnCompleted() { }
        public void OnError(Exception error) { }

        public void OnNext(KeyValuePair<string, object> @event)
        {
            // If we see some Lazy Loading, it means the developer needs to
            // fix their code!
            if (@event.Key.Contains("LazyLoading"))
                throw new InvalidOperationException(@event.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I used this to progressively get rid of lazy proxy use in our codebase:

```
if (enableProxies)
{
    builder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    var lazyLoadEvents = new[]
    {
        CoreEventId.NavigationLazyLoading,
        CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning,
        CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning,
    };
#if DEBUG
    builder.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(lazyLoadEvents));  //Lazyload now throws in DEBUG
#else
    if (sp.GetService<IHostEnvironment>()?.IsEnvironment("PRD") ?? false)
    {   //logs LazyLoad events as error everywhere else
        builder.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Log(lazyLoadEvents.Select(lle => (lle, LogLevel.Error)).ToArray())); 
    }
#endif
}
```

This makes the following. In production behavior is unchanged. In DEBUG an exception is raised when lazy-load is used. On qualification environments, an error is logged.